# How to report for all rows when joining?

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, window-functions, row-number

I'd like to report for all batch_runs that meet `where batch_run > 200833 and batch_id=100`

If a `BATCH_RUN` does not have any `batch_id = 100`, then report `0`.

```
  select batch_id,
       batch_run,
       count(*) over (partition by batch_id,
                                   batch_run
                          order by batch_run) as total_lot_count,
       sum(lot_size) over (partition by batch_id,
                                        batch_run) as total_lot_size,
       row_number() over (partition by batch_id
                               order by batch_run) as line_number

from batch_jobs  
-- inner join batches on batch_jobs.batch_run = batches.batch_run
-- left join batches on batch_jobs.batch_run = batches.batch_run  
where batch_run > 200833
and   batch_id = 100
```

See [Fidde](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c8a25/27)

```
BATCHES
--------------- ----------
BatchSequence   Batch_run
--------------- ----------
1                200833
2                200911
3                200922
4                200933
5                201011
6                201022
7                201033


BATCH_RUNS
------------- ---------- ---------
Batch_id      Batch_run  Lot_size 
------------- ---------- ---------
100            200933      10     
100            200933      20     
100            200933      30     
100            201022     400     
100            201022     500
```

Desired result:

```
--------------- --------- ---------- ----- ---- -------   
Batch_Run       Batch_id  Lot_count  Total_Lots Line_No
--------------- --------- ---------- ----- ---- -------
200911                                 0    1
200922            100       3         60    2
200933                                 0    3
201011                                 0    4
201022            100       2        900    5
201033                                 0    6
```

Comment: OK..I've resolved the `ora-918` errors. Regardles of which Join I use, now I'm not getting the 0 rows records in output. errors resolved here. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c8a25/19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's too bad that your post has inconsistencies with your SQL Fiddle.  It makes it all a bit confusing.  But I think that this is what you were looking for. And as you'll see, apart from `row_number`, analytic functions are not really needed.

```
select b.batch_run,
       bj.batch_id,
       count(bj.batch_run) as total_lot_count,
       coalesce(sum(bj.lot_size), 0) as total_lot_size,
       row_number() over (order by b.batch_sequence) as Line_No
  from batches b
  left join batch_jobs bj
    on bj.batch_run = b.batch_run
   and bj.batch_id = 100
 where b.batch_run > 200833
 group by b.batch_sequence, b.batch_run, bj.batch_id
 order by Line_No
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fd045/4)

Comment: Thanks for working past the confusion to find and illustrate a solution. You've been very helpful.